# Why does pull request show File Contents Unchanged for almost all files?

Tags: git, bitbucket, branching-and-merging, pull-request

Using Git and Bitbucket, I want to merge my feature branch into the general development branch by means of a pull request. The branching is as follows:

```
Master -> Development 1.0 -> Feature branch
Master -> Development 1.1
```

Development 1.0 was merged into Master before Development 1.1 was again branched from Master.

During development, I have merged Development 1.0, and after that Development 1.1, into my feature branch to update it with the code of other contributors. Now I want to merge **Feature branch** into **Development 1.1** by creating a pull request.

However when I do so on the Bitbucket page, it only shows changes for the two top-most files, all the other files are shown as '+0 -0' and 'File contents unchanged', even for files that are new and not on the development branch. Why does this happen? Did I mess something up by merging in the two different branches?

Directly merging (without creating a pull request) works as expected, so I would think that it is a pull request/Bitbucket-specifc problem, not an issue with my repository?

Comment: How many files did you uniquely modify in your `feature` branch?

Comment: Probably file permissions or line endings. Are you on Windows, working with colleagues on OSX or Linux (or vice-versa)?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not sure what you mean by 'uniquely modify', but 62 files are changed, of which 14 are new files. During development of the feature branch, about 5 - 10 of the existing files were also edited by colleagues on the development branch, which was then merged into my feature branch)

Comment: @Chris Everyone on the project is working on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Answering this myself because I **probably** have found the cause for this issue, which isn't something a lot of people will encounter.

I have found the specific commit from which the described behaviour started occuring. This commit happens to be on the same day that the client I had been using, Sourcetree, stopped working correctly.

I strongly suspect that SourceTree has somehow 'corrupted' the then-active branch when it was malfunctioning, which then resulted in this strange behaviour.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I have the same suspicion that a commit was somehow corrupted.

Comment: No I did not get this fixed, at least not in a proper way. If I recall correctly manually copy+pasting the files from the corrupt branch into a new branch and then creating a pull request worked as a workaround for pull request purposes, but of course you lose commit history information. The conclusion (without any evidence to back it up) remains that Sourcetree corrupted that branch when it stop working correctly that one day.

Comment: Thank you. I found my problem which may not have been the same thing. My problem was that the encoding type of some files that were imported into our repository weren’t UTF-8 so the internal git diff engine failed to render the results.